# Defining New Database to our QA Environment when it already exists in our UAT and Prod Environments

Tags: azure, azure-devops

So specifically, we need to define a New [DynamicsCRM] Database on our QA Azure Server. Now the knuckle curve ball is that this Database [DynamicsCRM] already exists in our UAT and Prod Environments. So when we get to that point to Pull Request, we want it to stop right there without ever having to cherry pick into the master branch and push it up because it already exists at the UAT and Prod Environments.

What do we need to do in this instance?

Answer (score 0):

Using Cherry Pick is a good choice for you situation. This is also what Cherry Pick used for.

Unlike a merge or rebase, cherry-pick only brings the changes from the commits you select, **instead of all the changes in a branch**.

Another way in my opinion (not familiar with code ). Not sure if you could use conditional statements to check which environment you are going to deploy based on something such as server name. If you detect the server name is QA environment, then choose to run the script/code to install Database. Otherwise do not install anything.